# Computer randomly shut down yesterday. Is there any malicious activity in the syslog?

Tags: shutdown, syslog

My computer suddenly turned off yesterday, and after searching here I found that I should look at the /var/log/syslog. But I have no idea what to look for, there were a lot of things happening around the time of the shutdown. I just want to know if there was any malicious activity by some external actor. I can not post the whole log here, but here is an excerpt of the last relevant lines (although the shutdown may have happened right before this so I don't know if it is relevant. However, even though I am not familiar at all with this log, some of the things there look quite strange). I will post the whole log somewhere if someone can recommend a good method for doing so (the whole log meaning from 10 seconds before what I posted now, there were a lot of things happening around 20:17:10).

```
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1520795840.6499] device (wlan0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1520795840.6532] manager: startup complete
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [wlan0]: new request (1 scripts)
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [wlan0]: start running ordered scripts...
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1520795840.8693] dnsmasq[0x99f900]: dnsmasq appeared as :1.85
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 dnsmasq[1980]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 dnsmasq[1980]: using nameserver 213.80.98.2#53(via wlan0)
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 dnsmasq[1980]: using nameserver 213.80.101.3#53(via wlan0)
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Wait Online.
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Reached target Timers.
Mar 11 20:17:20 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Started crash report submission daemon.
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 whoopsie[2058]: [20:17:21] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Starting Set console scheme...
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Started Set console scheme.
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 whoopsie[2058]: [20:17:21] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 whoopsie[2058]: [20:17:21] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 whoopsie[2058]: [20:17:21] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1520795841.7391] manager: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Mar 11 20:17:21 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1520795841.7394] manager: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Mar 11 20:17:22 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Started Daemon for generating UUIDs.
Mar 11 20:17:22 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 11 20:17:22 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 11 20:16:34 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1294]: Time has been changed
Mar 11 20:16:34 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 ntpdate[2090]: step time server 91.189.89.199 offset -53.780129 sec
Mar 11 20:16:34 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1073]: Time has been changed
Mar 11 20:16:34 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Mar 11 20:16:39 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 kernel: [   25.807814] dell_wmi: Unknown WMI event type 0x12
Mar 11 20:16:40 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 bluetoothd[754]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Mar 11 20:16:40 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 bluetoothd[754]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Mar 11 20:16:44 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[1439]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:2344): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:229: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
Mar 11 20:16:47 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd-timesyncd[609]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Mar 11 20:17:27 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 gnome-session[1584]: pkexec must be setuid root
Mar 11 20:17:28 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 gnome-session[1584]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Mar 11 20:17:47 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: powerd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 11 20:17:47 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 powerd[801]: SIGTERM recieved, cleaning up
Mar 11 20:18:18 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 112...
Mar 11 20:18:18 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1073]: Stopped target Default.
Mar 11 20:18:18 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1073]: Stopped Run Click user-level hooks.
Mar 11 20:18:18 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1073]: Stopped target Basic System.
Mar 11 20:18:18 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1073]: Stopped target Paths.
Mar 11 20:18:18 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1073]: Stopped target Timers.
Mar 11 20:18:18 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1073]: Stopped target Sockets.
Mar 11 20:18:18 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1073]: Reached target Shutdown.
Mar 11 20:18:18 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1073]: Starting Exit the Session...
Mar 11 20:18:18 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1073]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 2840 (kill).
Mar 11 20:18:18 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 112.
Mar 11 20:18:18 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of lightdm.
Mar 11 20:19:17 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: powerd.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Mar 11 20:19:17 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: powerd.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Mar 11 20:19:17 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Failed to start monitor and control system power state.
Mar 11 20:19:17 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: powerd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 11 20:19:17 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: powerd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Mar 11 20:19:17 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
Mar 11 20:19:17 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
Mar 11 20:19:17 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.
Mar 11 20:19:17 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Mar 11 20:19:17 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Mar 11 20:19:17 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Startup finished in 1.784s (kernel) + 3min 1.701s (userspace) = 3min 3.486s.
Mar 11 20:20:02 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Starting Stop ureadahead data collection...
Mar 11 20:20:02 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Stopped Read required files in advance.
Mar 11 20:20:02 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.
```

edit: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, dell Latitude E7250

Comment: What sort of system is this, what version of Ubuntu? There's something weird with your time, which might mean your CMOS battery needs replacing. Are you using Bluetooth and SSH? Are the nameservers correct, ie set by you or from your ISP; is this a Dell laptop? Is UID 112 your user?

Comment: `Mar 11 20:17:27 jonathan-Latitude-E7250 gnome-session[1584]: pkexec must be setuid root` makes me wonder if you've gone wild with `chmod` or `chown`.

Comment: @pbhj This is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, on a dell Latitude E7250 laptop. Sorry should have metioned that. There is definitely something going on with the time, that is the first thing I noticed. My bluetooth is indeed on (used it two days ago with a speaker), I think my computer is closed for ssh (tried ssh localhost->permission denied). No idea about UID 112. What do you mean by "are the nameservers correct"?

Comment: @waltinator Not recently, but I do  remember having to change something with chmod to fix something at some point a while ago and realized afterwards that it might not have been a recommended fix

Comment: If there is nothing in the logs you have to debug the kernel - https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html . IMO, historically, the main reasons are overheating and faulty hardware (memory test). The specter patch and microcode is also buggy and causes random reboots.

Comment: The lines you are posting from `/var/log/syslog` are during the reboot. The relevant lines needed would be during the shutdown phase. If they aren't present in `/var/log/syslog` look at the older file `/var/log/syslog.1`. However if system shutdown due to overheating chances are neither log will say why: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-find-out-from-the-logs-what-caused-system-shutdown If this only happens twice a year, Daylight Saving Time might be the culprit.

Comment: 213.80.98.2 is Bahnhof AB, if you don't recognise that company then someone else may have changed your nameservers to reroute your traffic; as that's a company this is highly unlikely. `ack 112 /etc/passwd` tells you the username of the UID 112 user, which should hint whether it's spurious, for me that was `saned` which is the user for the scanner driver. `sudo systemctl disable --now sshd.service` will disable the SSH daemon and stop it, you might have to do `mask`, see man pages. `zgrep -i ssh /var/log/auth.log*` will show attempted ssh logins recently.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix There are a lot of things happening at 20.17.10 in the log, but way too long to post here.

Comment: @pbhj I checked attempted ssh logins, and I have maany attempted logins from users all over the world. For example "Invalid user support from 113.172.164.82" followed by "input_userauth_request: invalid user support [preauth]". IP address is from Vietnam. Is this normal? :o might be completely unrelated to the shutdown though.

Comment: It's probably unrelated. It's not unusual. Either disable ssh or put it on a different port, mines 22XY where XY are arbitrary digits. Also fail2ban is good for blocking IP addresses that try to access your box.